# Multidimensionally explode(); tab-separated string of sequencial array keys

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array

I'm working with a view in Drupal and have been given a string like the following:

```
Room:  Bedroom Length:  5.00 Width:  5.00 Area:  25.00 Room:  Bathroom Length:  3.00 Width:  3.00 Area:  9.00
```

This is for two "room" objects, each with a length, width and area.

How would I explode this into a multidimensional array like the following:

```
array( [0] => array( [room] => "Bedroom" [length] => "5.00" [width] => "5.00" [area] => "25.00")
       [1] => array( [room] => "Bathroom" [length] => "3.00" [width] => "3.00" [area] => "9.00"))
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you know, first step would be putting the string in a variable, to be able to play with it. You would then split the string on "Room" but I will continue this example as if each $spec has 2 rooms.

```
//need the string in a variable ....  
$specs = "Room:  Bedroom Length:  5.00 Width:  5.00 Area:  25.00 Room:  Bathroom Length:  3.00 Width:  3.00 Area:  9.00";

//Explode your string on space caracter:
$specs_exploded = explode(" ", $specs);

// Then,  call the following function to build your array: 
$specs_array = build_specs($specs_exploded);

// Function that builds and returns specs_array. 
function build_specs(Array $specs){

    $spec_array = array();  

    $spec_array[] = array("room"   => $specs[1], 
                          "length" => $specs[3],
                          "width"  => $specs[5], 
                           // you could also set the key programmaticaly...
                           // the following woud give you "Area" => 25.00
                          $specs[6] => $specs[7],
                          );

                     // Second room
    $spec_array[] = array("room"  => $specs[9],

                         // etc...
                         );
   return $spec_array;
}
```

Note the example function handles 2 rooms exclusively. This could be better if you had one function that splits the string in "rooms" and returns an array of rooms, with strpos().

Pass the returned *rooms* array to a version of the above  example function that only handles one room at a time.

Hope this is enough to get you rolling, good luck!

Comment: I ended up just redoing the View so that the object actually flowed as an object instead of a string with weird separator characters; I needed to create a relationship for the complex field type I was working with. Regardless, accepting your answer because I probably would have used your code had I continued in this way.